# MVC3 Add Controller Context/Model Location

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, code-generation, t4

In my VS MVC project, for scaffolding purposes, the "Add Controller" dialogue offers me a list of potential db contexts and models from the current project.  But what if I have models and contexts in a seperate project?  How do I configure Visual Studio to search in extended locations?

Evidently others are able to see [all potential contexts and models from the "Add Controller" dialogue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890919/visual-studio-add-controller-list-of-model-classes).  I don't know why I can't.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should add the project that has models and contexts in References part of the project that has controller. 
References->Add Reference then browse for the project of models and contexts.

Also , you should put these projects in the same solution for this reference to work and you should build project in reference part before main one .

Comment: Both the steps you've described I had done, but unfortunately it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem!  In my solution, my MVC project was referencing the EF 4.1 assembly - while my supporting EF project was referencing an EF 4.2 assembly.  When I upgraded to have both of them match at 4.2, finally the "add controller" dialogue showed me all classes from both projects!